# Merged columns while exporting to .csv are not showing properly

Tags: angularjs, excel, csv, angular-ui-grid

I am using `angular-ui-grid` version `v3.0.0-rc.22-e8fe073`. In a grid there are few merged columns and the column definition of merged column is as below:

```
mergedColumn :true, mergedColumnDisplayName :'Client Buy', name:'buy',field:'buy','displayName':'Amount',enableHiding: false
```

Below is the headertemplate being used:

```
$scope.sHeaderTemplate ='<div class="ui-grid-header"> \
                        <div class="ui-grid-top-panel">\
                        <div class="ui-grid-header-viewport">\
                        <div class="ui-grid-header-canvas">\
                        <div class="ui-grid-header-cell-wrapper" ng-style="colContainer.headerCellWrapperStyle()">\
                        <div class="ui-grid-header-cell-row">\
                        <div class="ui-grid-header-cell ui-grid-clearfix" ng-if="!col.grouping"\
                            ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"\
                         col="col" render-index="$index"  ng-class="{\'ui-grid-header-cell-merged\': col.colDef.mergedColumnDisplayName}" >\
                         <div  class="ui-grid-header-cell-merged-title">&nbsp; {{col.colDef.mergedColumnDisplayName}} </div> \
                        </div>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="ui-grid-header-cell-row">\
                        <div class="ui-grid-header-cell ui-grid-clearfix" ng-if="!col.grouping"\
                            ng-repeat="col in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"\
                        ui-grid-header-cell col="col" render-index="$index">\
                        </div>\
                        </div>\
                        </div>\
                        </div>\
                        </div>\
                        </div>\
                        </div>';
```

And in a grid `headerTemplate :  $scope.sHeaderTemplate`.

Columns are displayed properly on a webpage. Please find below screenshot:

[image: merged column in a grid]

Now, when I export this grid to .csv and open the .csv file in `MS Excel`, I am not getting merged columns.

**How do I display merged columns from `angular-ui-grid` exported to csv in `MS Excel' ?**

Comment: There are no "merged columns" in the CSV format: it's a plain-text format with only values and separators.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Ok then how do I display merged column label in csv/ms-excel ?

Comment: You will need to search for how to create an actual Excel file from your grid, or maybe try exporting an an HTML table and giving it an xls extension. E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680768/export-to-xls-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExceJS](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#merged-cells) to create a merged cell, which sounds like what you are looking for.