# Exporting xlsx files in angular2 (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, xlsx

I need to get data to export to an xlsx file from an angular2 application that is in development.

Maybe I am really just looking for help getting a couple of libraries to load.
A couple of things I've found are this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd7jex9s/)
and this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27493796). I'd like to get something like this working, in angular2. Any attempts to get alasql to work have been met with errors stating it's not a module and such. Trying to follow approaches listed on various blogs, such as [this one](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/) result in errors like "cannot read property 'compile' of undefined"

In the previously mentioned
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd7jex9s/) is an example of what I'd like to get working:

```
var res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("MyAwesomeData.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[opts,[data1,data2]]);
```

I'm open to other tools, but the above would work for me -- if I could get it to work with angular2.

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 3):

To export json to excal file in angular 2, you can make use of alasql npm module.

1. Install npm modules

   ```
   i)  npm install --save alasql 
   ii) npm install --save xlsx
   ```
2. In angular-cli.json, under scripts add the following node module scripts

   ```
   "scripts": [
   "../node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.core.min.js",
   "../node_modules/xlsx/dist/xlsx.min.js",
   "../node_modules/alasql/dist/alasql.min.js"
   ```

   ]
3. In the component where you need to export the file add the below import statement: 
   `import * as alasql from 'alasql';`
4. On button click function add the following code:-

   ```
   buttonClick(){
   var data1 = [{a:1,b:10},{a:2,b:20}];
   var mystyle = {
     headers:true, 
     column: {style:{Font:{Bold:"1"}}},
     rows: {1:{style:{Font:{Color:"#FF0077"}}}},
     cells: {1:{1:{
       style: {Font:{Color:"#00FFFF"}}
     }}}
   };
    alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSXML("tdts.xls",?) FROM ?',[mystyle,data1]);
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have faced the same problem. Simple alasql is not angular 2 module but still you could use it with angular 2. simple include it like in the old way.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.12/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.3/alasql.min.js"></script>
```

then add this line after the imports in the component or the service file wher you need to use alasql.

```
declare let alasql
```

that works perfectly for me here is the [link](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/issues/738)

good luck