# I want to export the data of a dynamic html table,where pagination has been used,into an excel sheet using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to export the data of a dynamic paginated html table into an excel sheet using angular js. I have in google, but they all are working for static tables,not for the one I need. I have tried the below code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('Mycn',  function($scope) {

   $scope.exportfunc = function(){
   var strCopy = document.getElementById("MyTable").innerHTML;
   window.clipboardData.setData("Text", strCopy);
   var objExcel = new ActiveXObject ("Excel.Application");
   objExcel.visible = true;

   var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add;
   var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1);
   objWorksheet.Paste;
   }
});
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what the problem is with your current code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to xls using angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680768/export-to-xls-using-angularjs)

Comment: The button I have added is not working with this code. It is not exporting. Don't know why. My table is a dynamic table where pagination has been used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have used both Blob and Alasql. None of them worked. May be I missed something

Answer (score 0):

its posible using

> const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile const ExcelSheet =
>   ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet
>
> const title = 'Report Name' const columns = ['Account', 'Name']
>
> export class ComplaintExport extends Component {   createData = () =>
>   {
>       const { data, subtitle = 'Conversaciones' } = this.props
>
> ```
> const dataSet = [{ columns: [title], data: [] }, { columns: [subtitle], data: [] }, { columns: columns, data: data }]
> return dataSet   }   render() {
> const dataSet = this.createData()
> return (
>   <ExcelFile
>     element={
>       <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
>         Export All <Icon>attachment</Icon>
>       </Button>
>     }
>   >
>     <ExcelSheet dataSet={dataSet} name="Cons" />
>   </ExcelFile>
> )   }
> ```